# Detect reconnection after DBMS was down or unreachable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, atomikos

I am trying to pause JMS listeners when DBMS is unreachable and resume them right after the connection is back alive (so message delivery is not being retried and messages won't end up in DLQ). Datasource and connection is handled by **Atomikos** in **Spring boot** project.

The problem is **how to detect connection to DB is back alive** so I can resume my JMS listeners.

I have tried using **Spring AOP** and even full aspectj support without a success. With Spring AOP I am able to detect (the first) exception when there is a query to database, but not a test query (SELECT 1) and not a successful reconnect.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection())", throwing = "ex")
public void afterConnectionError(Exception ex) {
    // connection is broken, pausing JMS listeners
}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection())")
public void afterConnectionSuccess() {
    // connection is ok, if JMS listeners are paused -> resume
}
```

**Is it possible to use Spring AOP to catch atomikos datasource test query or what other approaches would you suggest for detecting a successful reconnect?**

One idea I have is to do a test query manually and repeatedly and act on its success/exception. This approach feels like reinventing the logic which is already there.